# Printing Ajax results in HTML

Tags: html, jquery, json

I have this J Query code: 
$(document).ready(function(){

```
                     var $outData = $('#data');
                     var ajaxUrl = 'url.json';
                     $.ajax(
                         {
                             type: 'GET',
                             url:ajaxUrl,
                             success: function (result) {
                                 console.log(result.passwords);   
                                 }
                             })
                         }
                     );
```

JSON file looks like this:

{
   "passwords":[
      {
         "value":"tom",
         "count":"432517"
      },
      {
         "value":"anaconda",
         "count":"454658"
      },
      {
         "value":"111111",
         "count":"148079"
      },

What I need to do, is to print out each of these objects to be printed out in an ordered list (for instance it should look like this:

1. tom 432517
2. anaconda 454658
3. 111111 148079

So far, nothing I have tried works. Althoug, I can console.log the entire object. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your code doesn't show any attempt to print the items in a list. You say you've tried this but it didn't work. Can you show us your attempt?

Comment: Instead of `console.log(result.passwords);` try `result.password.forEach(pwd => console.log(pwd.value, pwd.count));` if that's what you need?!

Comment: @Benny I have tried your suggestion, and it returns `index.html:47 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined`

Comment: My typo: should be *result.passwords.forEach*

Comment: @Benny Yes, this almost solved my issue Although, one more small thing left to do. I was console loggin it just to make sure, that AJAX is working. However, i need it to be printed in HTML, instead of console.

Comment: Glad it works. To display on the page means doing something like *$outData.append(...)* Inside the *forEach* loop

Comment: @Darius See an example in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example rendering:

```
var $outData = $('#data');
                     var ajaxUrl = 'url.json';
                     $.ajax(
                         {
                             type: 'GET',
                             url:ajaxUrl,
                             success: function (result) {
                                 result.passwords.forEach(pwd => $outData.append(`<div>${pwd.value} ${pwd.count}</div>`));   
                                 }
                             })
                         }
                     );
```

Comment: Brilliant. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

you can create elements and append to dom when you are done,

```js
const data = {
  "passwords": [{
      "value": "tom",
      "count": "432517"
    },
    {
      "value": "anaconda",
      "count": "454658"
    },
    {
      "value": "111111",
      "count": "148079"
    }
  ]
}
const ol = document.createElement("ol");
for (const {
    value,
    count
  } of data.passwords) {
  const li = document.createElement("li")
  li.innerText = `${value} -> ${count}`
  ol.appendChild(li)
}
document.querySelector("#root").appendChild(ol)
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Since my object has 50 pairs, does that mean I would need each of them manually?

Comment: do you see in my snippet me doing anything manually for those 3 pairs ?